# Tkinter window closing abruptly without displaying output

Tags: python, tkinter

`tkinter` is working fine normally, but window closes automatically without even showing any output when I add this line

`left = Label(self.root, image=self.left).place(x=80, y=100, relwidth=400, relheight=500`

```py
from tkinter import*

from PIL import Image,ImageTk

class Register:

    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root=root
        self.root.title("Material Calculator")
        self.root.geometry("1350x700+0+0")

    # BG image

        self.bg=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="D:/tkinter_Navjot/back.jpg")
        bg=Label(self.root,image=self.bg).place(x=250,y=0,relwidth=1,relheight=1)

    # LEFT image

        self.left = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="D:/tkinter_Navjot/side1.jpg")
        left = Label(self.root, image=self.left).place(x=80, y=100,relwidth=400,relheight=500)

root=Tk()

obj=Register(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Matiiss `relwidth` and `relheight` can have values > 1, e.g. you can create a label with width = 1.5 of its parent width.  What OP issue is that it creates a very very big label that `tkinter` cannot handle.

Comment: Yes, `relheight` and `relwidth` with those large values give me an extremely unresponsive window but the window shows. Try with values `<1` and the window will work correctly.

Comment: What is the point of creating a label that is 500x taller and 400x wider than the window?

Comment: @BryanOakley: Perhaps it was a typo, and they meant simply `width` and `height`, since they seem to be trying to give the dimensions in pixels.

Comment: Thankyou, now I understood I should have used width and height